# How to invoke COM function in Octave that takes input parameter?

Tags: windows, com, octave, ole, forge

I use Octave 5.1.0 with "windows" package installed (from Octave Forge).
I use it to access COM interface of a windows app.

I can see the COM functions using:

```
h = actxserver('MyApp.Application')
com_invoke(h)
```

I can access COM function that doesn't take any parameter:

```
com_invoke(h, "GetStatus")
```

However, for function that takes one parameter, I couldn't find the right syntax.
I have tried these below to no avail:

```
com_invoke(h, "SetType", 1)
com_invoke(h, "SetType(1)")
com_invoke(h, "SetType", {1})
com_invoke(h, "SetType", ({1}))
com_invoke(h, "SetType[1]")
com_invoke(h, "SetType", [1])
com_invoke(h, "SetType", "1")
```

I have been searching online, couldn't find any info.

What is the correct way to invoke COM function that takes an input parameter?

Comment: This 'windows' package (source is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/windows/ci/default/tree/src/__COM__.cc) seems to support a limited set of COM/Automation types. So, it may not work depending on your 'MyApp.Application' COM object.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks Simon. It's just a function that take 1 parameter, I would imagine it's pretty common and often needed. Anyway, looks like I can't use it then.

Comment: It's not related to the number of parameters, but more to their type and/or direction (in/out/ref, etc.). As you can check in the source, the octave_to_com function seems to support only  BSTR (string) BOOL (boolean), R8 (IEEE double), array of R8, array of VARIANT, and IDISPATCH (objects). This doesn't cover all what you can build in your COM object.

Comment: @SimonMourier Oh I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I found that the way I declare my COM function is not correct. After I fixed it, now it works fine.

```
com_invoke(h, "SetType", 1)
```

The problem was, I didn't declare my COM function in DISP_FUNCTION properly (the input parameter).